# I connected to mongodb with next js, but the session appears undefined

Tags: mongodb, next.js, github-api

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "../../../util/mongo";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GithubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    pages: {
        signIn: "/auth/login",
    },
 
});
```

```
adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise)
```

When I delete it, the data comes back, but when I add it to mongodb and save it, it comes back undefined.